$\int_0^R \frac{r^{l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\text dr$
I'm trying to solve problem 3.3 from Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, but I'm encountering some troubles solving
$$
\int_0^R \frac{r^{l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\text dr, 
\qquad l = 0,2,4,6,\ldots
$$
As far I know, this integral equals to
$$R^{2l+1} \frac{(2l)!!}{(2l+1)!!},$$
where $l!! = l(l-2)!! = l(l-2)(l-4)!!$ is a double factorial.
First problem: this integral doesn't appear in my integrals table (could you recommend one?). Second problem: I tried the substitution $r = R\sin t$ but it didn't help.
So, can you tell a nice substitution to solve this or the name of a book that may have this particular integral? Please don't use the beta function in the answer you may give, I don't know how to use it.
UPDATE
Using substitutions $r = Rx$ (as suggested) and $\xi = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$,
$$
\int_0^R \frac{r^{l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\text{d}r
= R^{l+1}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{l+1}}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\text{d}x
= R^{l+1}\int_0^1 (1 - \xi^2)^{l/2}\text{d}\xi
$$
Giving values $l = 0,2,4,6,\ldots$ ($l$ even) I managed to deduce the 2nd equation of the post. So the question can be consider answered

Try integration by parts to get a recurrence relation.

For $\ell > 0$, integration by parts yields
$$
\int_0^R r^{\ell} \cdot \frac{r}{R^2 - r^2},dr = \ell \int_0^R r^{\ell - 1}\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}.
$$
Perhaps that's helpful

Yes, both comments are usefull but a I was looking for something more straightforward, without doing integration by parts many times

You could use $r=R\sin t$ then look up the Beta function.

Are you solving a physics problem where $R$ is the radius of some entity such as a thin shell?

Note that $\int_0^R \frac{r^{2l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}dr
=R^{2l+1}I_{2l+1}$, with $$I_{2l+1}= \int_0^1 \frac{r^{2l+1}}{\sqrt{1- r^2}}dr =\frac{2l}{2l+1}I_{2l-1} =  \frac{2^l l!}{(2l+1)!!} I_0$$

Recurrence is probably the easiest way. You don't need to do integration by parts "many times" - just the general version in terms of $\ell$ once. And that's almost in Ben Grossman's comment (but with a minor error).

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Yes, the problem is a conductor disk at fixed potencial and density charge. I need to find the potencial using spherical harmonics. See problem 3.3 in Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics.

@aschepler How would be that general version? In Ben Grossman's comment he solves the integral but he gets one more to solve.

It's the general version of integration by parts for any $\ell$, not the final answer.

We don't really "close" answered questions. You can click the checkmark by someone's answer to select it as most helpful. Or you can write your own answer with the method you ended up using, and then checkmark that.

Let $r=R\sin\theta$, then
$$\int_0^R \frac{r^{l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} d r =R^{l+1} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{l+1} \theta d \theta  $$
For the integral $I_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^n x d x$, $$
\begin{aligned}
I_n&=-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{n-1} x d(\cos x) \\
& =(n-1) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^2 x \sin ^{n-2} x d x \\
& =(n-1) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-\sin ^2 x\right) \sin ^{n-2} x d x \\
& =(n-1) I_{n-2}-(n-1) I_n \\
\therefore I_n&=\frac{n-1}{n} I_{n-2} .
\end{aligned}
$$
by which we can reduce the power by two and so on as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2 l+1} \theta d \theta & =I_{2 l+1} \\
& =\frac{2 l}{2 l+1} \cdot \frac{2 l-2}{2 l-1} \cdots \frac{2}{3} \cdot I_1 \\
& =\frac{(2 l)!!}{(2 l+1)!!}
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\int_0^R \frac{r^{2 l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} d r=R^{2 l+1} \frac{(2 l)!!}{(2 l+1)!!}
$$

Making the substitution $r=Rx^{1/2}$, the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int_0^R \frac{r^{l+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\,dr
&=\int_0^1\frac{R^{l+1}x^{(l+1)/2}}{\sqrt{R^2-R^2x}}\,\frac{R\,dx}{2\sqrt{x}} \\
&=\frac{R^{l+1}}{2}\int_0^1 x^{l/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}\,dx \\
&=\frac{R^{l+1}}{2}\,B\left(\frac{l}{2}+1,\frac{1}{2}\right), \tag{1}
\end{align}
where
$$
B(z_1,z_2)=\int_0^1t^{z_1-1}(1-t)^{z_2-1}\,dt=\frac{\Gamma(z_1)\Gamma(z_2)} {\Gamma(z_1+z_2)} \tag{2}
$$
is the Beta function.

Damn...how did you see it?

Let $r=x\,R$ then
$$I=\int \frac{r^{L+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\,dr=R^{L+1}\int\frac{ x^{L+1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$
Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\frac{R^{L+1} }{L+2} \,x^{L+2}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{L+2}{2};\frac{L+4}{2};x^2\right)$$and the definite integral is then, after simplifcations,
$$I=\int_0^R \frac{r^{L+1}}{\sqrt{R^2 - r^2}}\,dr=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, R^{L+1}\,\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{L+2}{2}\right)}{2 \,\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{L+3}{2}\right)}$$
